# Why are the Text fields not wrapping?

Tags: html, aws-amplify

I have this card definition. Notice the text fields have `wrap` enabled.

```js
<Card
    width={"40rem"}
    variation={"elevated"}
    key={index}
    padding="1rem"
    textAlign={"left"}
    backgroundColor={"blue.20"}
    fontSize={"1.5rem"}>
    <Flex
        direction="row"
        justifyContent="flex-start"
        alignItems="flex-start"
        alignContent="flex-start"
        gap="1rem">
        <Text
            width="2.25rem">
            {item.Number}
        </Text>
        <Text
            wrap="wrap"
            height="3.0rem"
            width="10.25rem">
            {item.Name}
        </Text>
        <Text
            wrap="wrap"
            height="3.0rem"
            width="19.25rem">
            {item.Description}
        </Text>
        <Rating
            maxValue={1}
            value={item.Variations.length}
            icon={<ImVideoCamera/>}/>
    </Flex>
</Card>
```

But on rendering, the text fields do not wrap as expected. I get results like this:

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?